# Microsoft Identity Platform Multitenant Restrictions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, microsoft-identity-platform

I am currently developing an Azure Web App, which uses the Microsoft identity platform. Everything works fine as a single- and multi-tenant application. I only have one big problem, where I did not find any good solution, or at least best practices.

I would like the application to support multiple tenants. This means that I definitely need a multi-tenant application. Anyways, this allows ALL Microsoft users to access my Web App, which I highly do not want. The business plan is as follows: Businesses buy the subscription/product and then gain access to the application (initially manually).

At first I thought that there might be some sort of setting in Azure to manually white-/blacklist certain tenants directly in the portal. I did not find anything regarding this, but maybe I missed it.

My second thought is, that I have to implement the logic in the server directly. This should not be a problem, but are there already any existing resources you can use, regarding this? My idea was that after/before each redirect to a page, the server checks the database, if the tenant is allowed to visit the page. If not, a redirect to a "You are not allowed to visit this page!" page should happen.

Did I miss anything major here? I am 100% certain, that this is a somewhat common use-case and therefore am baffled that I did not find anything relevant regarding this.

Comment: Did you happen to check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/tenant-restrictions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single-tenant applications can be accessed only by users who have an organizational account in the same AAD where the application is registered. Multi-tenant applications can on the other hand be accessed by anyone who has a valid organizational account.

The first time you try to authenticate to a multi-tenant application it isn't registered with your organization's AAD. You have to trigger the [consent flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#understand-user-and-admin-consent) which will allow the user to login with their organizational account and grant the application the necessary permissions.

One way to solve your problem is by restricting access to tenants in Azure Active Directory. Check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/tenant-restrictions) for detailed information.

Another way is by setting up  sign-in for multi-tenant Azure Active Directory using custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C. Check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) for more information.